# Tor on WD My Cloud device

Tags: configuration, raspberry-pi

Anyone have any luck running `tor` on a Western Digital My Cloud NAS?  Is there any guide for running `tor` on new embedded devices? Any guidelines for resources like memory?

Comment: I run Tor on a QNAP NAS. It has a plugin system that lets you install optware ipkg package manager. Maybe the MyCloud has something similar. From there I setup compiler, libraries, headers to build Tor from source.

Comment: I clarified my question with "Any guidelines for resources like memory?"  QNAP looks more hefty than My Cloud but low end QNAPs have 512mb RAM too.  Raspberry Pi's have that too, so that's good.  Concern : http://shortattentionspade.com/how-to-make-your-wd-mycloud-suck-less-or-for-seo-purposes-improving-the-performance-of-your-wd-mycloud/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It installs with no issue, enable SSH, login as root, and type

```
apt-get install tor
```

As for memory usage, many people run it on routers, which have only 32MB of memory.

There is no GUI for setting it up AFAIK, and will require the usual command line tinkering – if you are comfortable with that.

Warning: I've not personally tried using it, only installing it.

BIG BIG GOTCHA: You'll need to be running a "normal" (non 64k page size) kernel, which you can install following the instructions here: http://community.wd.com/t5/WD-My-Cloud/Clean-debian-and-OpenMediaVault-on-WDMyCloud/td-p/785505

Comment: Interesting, thanks for pointing out that and OMV.